# Extrating embedded styles from an HTML page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

So, here's the problem...

I have to:

1. Grab a page of html via a REST API with a AJAX call,
2. Extract a table with a known id from that html (which, thankfully, is well-formed)
3. Extract the associated css for the table from a style block,
4. Append the table to a div on my page, and
5. Re-apply the original CSS

Therefore the parts of the page that I'm interested in are:

```
<style>
 #tableid td.someclass {
  ...
  }
 #tableid td.anotherclass {
  ...
  }
 [etc etc ..]
</style>
```

And

```
<table id="tableid">
 ...
</table>
```

So, going through the list above 1,2 & 4 are no problem at all. It's 3 and 5 that are taxing the brain - there are no external stylesheets to worry about BTW, everything is in the page that I'm grabbing inside a single  tag.

I guess I could extract the entire  element and then append it to my page - but that is messy and could result in unwanted side-effects. What I'd like to do is just extract the styling that applies to #tableid and then apply them the table appended to my div.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could pull the styles from the header using a standard jQuery finder:

```
var styles = $('head style').text();
```

Then run a regular expression against it:

```
var tableID     = 'tableid',
    pattern     = new RegExp('#'+ tableID + '[^}]+}', 'g'),
    tableStyles = styles.match(pattern);
```

This should give you an array of styles for your table’s id. Now you can append these styles to your current document’s head:

```
$('<style/>', { text: tableStyles.join('\n') }).appendTo('head');
```

Your use case might require some fine–tuning, but this should approximately give you what you’re after.